# Maven on eclipse cant download in repo

Tags: java, spring, eclipse, maven

Why my maven cant download in mvn repo? im having this error.

```
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org -> [Help 1]
```

I also tried to set the proxy

```
 <proxies>
<proxy>
   <active>true</active>
   <protocol>https</protocol>
   <host>host</host>
   <port>port</port>
  </proxy>
```

but i can also access https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 on my chrome.

Comment: Have you tried add a dns mapping for repo.maven.apache.org in your host file (in the case of window user)?

Comment: @VinhNT nope i dont have permission to modify it

Comment: The error message: repo.maven.apache.org: Unknown host repo.maven.apache.org, 
It means that your machine is unable to find the ip address of repo.maven.apache.org

Comment: @VinhNT thanks for the info, is there any other workaround to solve this?

Comment: If you have able to build the app successfully before, try with the mvn install -O (upper case 'o')
Or try with uk repository: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-mirror-settings.html

Comment: try changing the protocol to http also you mentioned that chrome can access it ...have you set proxy to chrome if so, set the same values in settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your network firewall is blocking and you need to talk to your network admin. You are able to access this from chrome as it is not in blocked list but running maven command executes in different manner.
Also you can make sure this running same application on different system which is not under firewall(maybe on your own laptop)